# Get python data from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

So I'm trying to make a problem for a ctf, and for a problem, I need to send data from a python script to the javascript. Can anyone tell me how?

Thanks!

My html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 class="text">text</h1>
        <script>
            $.get("http://[website]/cgi-bin/challenge.py", 
                function(data) {
                $(".text").html(data);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I replaced the website name with [website]
The python code is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
text = "It works!"
json.dumps(text)
```

**Edit:**
I expected the python file to return "It works!", however after going into the network tab to see the result, it returned nothing. The text in the h1 also disappeared.

This is an image from the network tab:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JSMO.png

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Added what happens. If necessary, I can put the website where the error is happening in there.

Comment: What happens when you go to that file directly? Does it display "It works!"? Is the website located at the same address as where the HTML is located (Is this a Cross Site Request)?

Comment: Can you show the output from the network tab? Is it a 200 response, or perhaps an invalid one

Comment: When I go to the website directly, it's a blank page. The output from the network tab is a 200 response.

Comment: So clearly the issue isn't in the HTML, it's in the python, as when you goto the page directly, nothing is output. So investigate from there: *Why wouldn't `json.dumps` output anything?* Perhaps it's because `json.dumps` only RETURNS the string. How about printing that string out instead?

Comment: When adding 
    print text

All it does is print "It works!" What I want is to be able to use that value in javascript, without actually seeing what the value is when I do Ctrl + U

Comment: Hii,add this print  statement too. print "Acces-Control-Allow-Origin: *"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing `print()` and content-type `application/json` because `json.dumps()` will not print output or set header to JSON.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json

text = json.dumps("It works!")

print "Content-Type: application/json\n"
print(text)
```